# Difference between "open up" and "open", optional "up" & "down" words

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I don't really understand why we add the word `up` or `down` even if it is not needed, example : `open up!` when requesting/ordering someone to open the door.
Why not just say `open the door!`, or `open!`, what's the purpose of `up` in examples like these ?

The same thing with adding the word `down`, that I hear in many sentences, but I don't really have one in mind right now.

EDIT : What's the difference between `open the door!` & `open up the door!` ?

Comment: You have to provide concrete examples for each. Open up! [no space] is the same as Open the door! To shut down a business is not to shut a business. So, it all depends on context, really. In all senses of the term.

Comment: @Lambie I edited my question to add a simple example

Comment: You need an example with shut and shut down. [open not upen] And please remove the spaces in front of the exclamation marks.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks I fixed the spaces. I do understand the difference between "shut" and "shut down", but I don't understand the difference in "open the door!" and "open up the door!". (Like I've seen in many movies when someonen is yelling at a person to open a door)

Comment: "Open up" is used in the context of someone opening a (possibly locked) door or gate to let someone else in, perhaps reluctantly. As you say, when the person outside is 'yelling at them'. 'Up' just adds emphasis to the command.